# Compare two parent objects

Tags: apex, master-detail, junction-object, lookup-filter

I have a junction object which has a master detail relationship to account and market. This junction object can only be created from account. When user clicks new, Account will already be prefilled but user can only add a market if city field on market,which is a multiselect,  contains the city selected on the account object otherwise it throws an error. How can i compare two lookup fields on insert?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [validation rule.](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_field_validation.htm) Your formula for your validation rule will probably be something like

```
Account.BillingCity <> Market__r.City__c
```

Edit for multi-select picklist:

```
NOT(CONTAINS(Market__r.City__c, Account.BillingCity))
```

Comment: I should have added that the city field on market is a multiselect hence i was not able to use the validation rules

Comment: You should still be able to do it. See my updated answer.